# Mouse position on the internal camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

What do I have:

- `Camera2D` that looks down on the **Plane**, horizontally in a global system
- The Image from **Camera2D** is saved to the **Texture2D**
- `MainCamera` which displays **Canvas** from the **UI**
- There is a `RawImage` in **Canvas** to which **Texture2D** is assigned

**In short, in **Main UI** I have a screen in which I display the content of another camera.**

My problem:

- I'd like to draw something on `Plane`.
- To do this I need to find a mapping of the **Mouse Position** in the global coordinate system

I try to do it in different ways, e.g.

```
var mp = Input.mousePosition;
var vec = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mp);
//var vec = image2DCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mp);
```

This solution works when there is only one camera, but in this case it does not fulfill its purpose.

How to do it correctly in such a situation?

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
Plane plane = new Plane(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
float distance;

var mp = Input.mousePosition;
var mp2 = new Vector3(mp.x, mp.y, 100);
Ray ray = image2DCamera.ScreenPointToRay(mp2);
if (plane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
{
    worldPosition = ray.GetPoint(distance);
}

Debug.Log("mp : " + mp2);
Debug.Log("worldPosition : " + worldPosition);
```

Comment: So I don't quite understand how exactly you want to draw... which camera do you want to use for drawing? Does anything speak against a simple `Physics.Raycast` using `someCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition)` and then calculate the pixel coordinate from the hot point?

Comment: In both your attempts you are missing the distance to the camera as the `z` component of the vector .. you only pass in the screen space `Input.mousePosition` but this one has `z = 0` .. you'll have to provide the distance from the camera as `z` in a new Vector3

Comment: @derHugo I also used `Physics.Raycast` but it gives the same result. I added a code snippet as I check it. For `Z`, no matter what he enters, the result does not change. Note that I am doing `image2DCamera.ScreenPointToRay`. This solution does not work for `mainCamera`. Returns an error. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it in a simple way. Without using Ray etc.

Below is the code with the added cube that shows how the mouse moves on the UI screen (`RawImage`) and on the `Plane` in another place.

It also works fine with `Camera Zoom`.

```
public class MyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera portalCamera; // Camera for 2D View
    public RawImage texture2DView; // Rect on UI with 2D View

    GameObject mouseCube;

    DomaManager domaManager;

    void Start()
    {
        domaManager = DomaManager.Instance;

        mouseCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        mouseCube.name = "MouseCube";
        mouseCube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
        mouseCube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var mp = Input.mousePosition;

        int marginLeft = Mathf.RoundToInt(((Screen.width - texture2DView.rectTransform.rect.width) / 2) + texture2DView.transform.localPosition.x);
        int marginBottom = Mathf.RoundToInt(((Screen.height - texture2DView.rectTransform.rect.height) / 2) + texture2DView.transform.localPosition.y);

        Rect rect2DUI = new Rect(marginLeft, marginBottom, texture2DView.rectTransform.rect.width, texture2DView.rectTransform.rect.height);

        if (rect2DUI.Contains(mp))
        {
            // Mouse Position in areaTexture2D
            var rectUIMousePosition = new Vector3(mp.x - rect2DUI.xMin, mp.y - rect2DUI.yMin, mp.z);

            // Position corners camera rect
            //var topRight = secondCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, secondCamera.nearClipPlane));
            //var topLeft = secondCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 1, secondCamera.nearClipPlane));
            //var bottomleft = secondCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, secondCamera.nearClipPlane));
            //var bottomRight = secondCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 0, secondCamera.nearClipPlane));

            // Mouse Position in camera area
            var positionInCameraRect = portalCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(rectUIMousePosition.x / portalCamera.pixelWidth, rectUIMousePosition.y / portalCamera.pixelHeight, portalCamera.nearClipPlane));

            var realePositionInCameraRect = new Vector3(positionInCameraRect.x, 0, positionInCameraRect.z);

            // Cube follow Mouse Position
            mouseCube.transform.position = realePositionInCameraRect;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]